# When Trying to update the above Query in MS SQL SERVER ,it is saying ZERO rows affected

Tags: sql-server

```
Update a 
set approvedby = 'Matt Schmitt', changenumber = 'CHG48038', effectiveenddatetime = 'DEC  31 2199 11:59PM' 
from esg_staging..enoc_auditexceptions a 
join esg_staging..enoc_auditresult b 
on a.[WorkdayValue] = b.workdayvalue 
    and a.[Applicationvalue] = b.applicationvalue 
    and a.name = b.name 
    and a.workdayid = b.workdayid 
    and a.email = b.email 
    and a.application = '29905'
```

Comment: That's nice. Did you have a question? this site is for questions, not a place to dump random queries which apparently match no records.

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: You'll have to add the schema of the tables you're using to your question to have any sort of hope of getting help.

Comment: I wanted to know that why it is not showing 1 row affected instead of 0 rows

Comment: Because no rows match your criteria. It's impossible to answer *why* without knowing the actual values

Comment: Query is fine, but the data is missing. There is no application 29905 in `exceptions` or (workdayvalue, applicationvalue, name, workdayid, email) in `results` - I would bet on second because I suspect null values in email or name columns.

Comment: yes there is null values

Answer (score 0):

Try These if you are updating from another table

Update esg_staging.enoc_auditexceptions
set approvedby = b.approvedby
, changenumber = b.changenumber `enter code here`
, effectiveenddatetime = b.effectiveenddatetime

from esg_staging.enoc_auditexceptions a 
join esg_staging.enoc_auditresult b on a.[WorkdayValue] = b.workdayvalueand a.[Applicationvalue] = b.applicationvalue 
and a.name = b.name and a.workdayid = b.workdayid and a.email = b.email and a.application = '29905'

Comment: First, this should be a comment. Second, how does this answer the question? What is the difference from the original code? The lack of an alias? This won't make any difference